# Can't get mysql running

Tags: mysql

After canceling an Ubuntu upgrade, Mysql refuses to start.

this is what I get when I try to run it :

```
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

When I try starting it using `service` command I get this :

```
$ service mysql start
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.74" (uid=1000 pid=16096 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

I tried also to uninstall it but I get this error :

```
$ sudo apt-get remove mysql
E: dpkg a été interrompu. Il est nécessaire d'utiliser « sudo dpkg --configure -a » pour corriger le problème.
```

The error is in french, but those familiar with Ubuntu will get it I guess.

After that I do what they suggested :

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Paramétrage de mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
```

And then it endlessly configures.. until I get this error :

```
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg : erreur de traitement de mysql-server-5.5 (--configure) :
le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
mysql-server-5.5
```

almost the same thing when I try an `autoremove` :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :
  libdevil1c2 libgearman6 libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin liblasi0 libtokyocabinet8
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 6 à enlever et 6 non mis à jour.
1 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 3 232 ko d'espace disque seront libérés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer [O/n] ? O
(Lecture de la base de données... 536300 fichiers et répertoires déjà     installés.)
Suppression de libdevil1c2 ...
Suppression de libgearman6 ...
Suppression de libgts-bin ...
Suppression de libgts-0.7-5 ...
Suppression de liblasi0 ...
Suppression de libtokyocabinet8 ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour « libc-bin »...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour « man-db »...
Paramétrage de mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg : erreur de traitement de mysql-server-5.5 (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 mysql-server-5.5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My Mysql version is :

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

Any hints about this ?

Answer (score 1):

1 - What message do you get when you try to restart mysql ? : `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

2 - Verify if the `/var/run/mysqld` directory is owned by `mysql`, if it's not th case, create a new directoy and assign it to `mysql` :

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql mysqld
```

And restart the mysqld daemon :

```
sudo mysqld_safe
```

Comment: Usually, the daemon starter will only send the start to the specific daemon, then look for it for a number of seconds, and drop a generic error message if it didn't come up. You can get specific error messages from the mysql logs under /var/log/mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Cheap but useful workaround:

```
mysql -u <user> -p -h <127.0.0.1> -P <port>
```